# How to sync media perfectly in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video

Let's say I would like to synchronize two videos and avoid echos. I meant that the two tracks should stay in sync as though playing a regular video file with audio.

```
<video id="A" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm" controls=""></video><br>
<p>Current Time:<span id="aTime"></span></p><br>
<video id="B" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm" controls=""></video><br>
<p>Current Time:<span id="bTime"></span></p><br>
<button onclick="playM()">Play</button>
<button onclick="pauseM()">Pause</button>
<script>
var a = document.getElementById("A");
var b = document.getElementById("B");
function playM() {
a.play();
b.play();
}
function pauseM() {
a.pause();
b.pause();
}
a.ontimeupdate = function() {
document.getElementById("aTime").innerHTML = a.currentTime;
};
b.ontimeupdate = function() {
document.getElementById("bTime").innerHTML = b.currentTime;
};
a.onseeked = function() {
b.currentTime= a.currentTime;
};
b.onseeked = function() {
a.currentTime = b.currentTime;
};
</script>
```

Comment: Is my question too easy or unclear so that no one answer? I did have researched a lot but found nothing.

Comment: Actually your question would be harder to answer last year because asynchronous JavaScript was hard to accomplish. Just a couple of months ago `async` and `await` were released by every browser except for IE (IE isn't really a browser, it's a big mistake). See my answer. BTW I synced 2 identical videos to demonstrate that they are truly synchronized. By listening during playback, you'll hear no echo. A video and audio can be synchronized but it's pointless to do so if they are entirely different.

Comment: Note that the videos' load times are logged in milliseconds, the difference between them are very small at an average of @0.4 ms. that's like 400 **micro**seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

After some experimentation, I've discovered that the an offset of mere microseconds is great, *but* not really necessary for syncing videos. In Demo 2 we have video tag A and B. A has 4 `eventListener()` and video B as the callback. `play()`, `pause()`, and `seek` are synced between A and B with A being the "master" and B the "slave".

### Demo 2

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    html {
      font: 400 16px/1.5 Consolas
    }
    
    section {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-around;
      width: 100%;
      height: calc(100% - 160px);
    }
    
    button {
      padding: 0;
      border: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <video id="A" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm" controls width='240' height='135'></video>
    <video id="B" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm" controls width='240' height='135'></video>
  </section>


  <script>
    var A = document.getElementById("A");
    var B = document.getElementById("B");


    A.addEventListener("play", function() {
      B.play();
    });

    A.addEventListener("pause", function() {
      B.pause();
    });

    A.addEventListener("seeking", function() {
      B.currentTime = A.currentTime;
    });

    A.addEventListener("seeked", function() {
      B.currentTime = A.currentTime;
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

JavaScript is synchronous, meaning that it processes one thing at a time. Syncing media is possible by using `Promise`s which allows asynchronous operations but it's syntax is unintuitive and down right difficult. Fortunately `async` and `await` just got released in all major browsers* only a couple of months ago. All of the behavior and flow of `Promise`s are in `await`. Here's the basic syntax involved using 2 functions asynchronously:

```
async function functionName() {
  var A = await functionA();
  var B = await functionB();
  var C = A + B;
  return C;
}
```

---

**Details are commented in Demo**

**References are at the bottom of post**

### Demo

```js
/* For details on how this demo controls the <form>, 
|| see HTMLFormControlsCollection in References
*/
var x = document.forms.ui.elements;
var playM = x.playM;
var pauseM = x.pauseM;

/* Register the buttons to the click event
|| callback is asyncCall()
|| Register a video tag to the ended event
|| callback is just an anonymous function to
|| display 'IDLE' message when the videos have ended
*/
/* Avoid the use of on event handlers, use event
|| listeners instead. For details on Event Listeners
|| see addEventListener() in References
*/
playM.addEventListener('click', asyncCall, false);

pauseM.addEventListener('click', asyncCall, false);

document.querySelector('video').addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
  x.display.value = 'IDLE';
}, false);

/* This callback is an Async Function which uses a key
|| word called "await". await waits for a function
|| to start then moves on to the next await to 
|| see when it's ready to start. The players are 
|| playing asynchronously (i.e. congruently, i.e i.e. in 
|| parallel). Normally JavaScript is synchronous because
|| the evaluation and execution of a function is the
|| only thing a browser would do, so everything else
|| had to wait their turn. That is called: "blocking".
|| While await is waiting, the browser is allowed to do
|| other processing. For details on async and await,
|| see References.
*/
async function asyncCall(e) {
  var A = document.getElementById("A");
  var B = document.getElementById("B");
  var status;
  
  /* if/if else condition to determin which button was
  || actually clicked. Use e.target to get the origin
  || of event (i.e. clicked button). For details on
  || Event.target, see References
  */
  // if the button's #id is 'playM'...
  if (e.target.id === 'playM') {
    var mediaA = await mPlay(A);
    x.outA.value = performance.now(mediaA);
    var mediaB = await mPlay(B);
    x.outB.value = performance.now(mediaB);
    status = mPlay(B);
    
  // otherwise if the button's #id is 'pauseM'... 
  } else if (e.target.id === 'pauseM') {
    var mediaA = await mIdle(A);
    x.outA.value = performance.now(mediaA);
    var mediaB = await mIdle(B);
    x.outB.value = performance.now(mediaB);
    status = mIdle(B);
  } else {
    status = 'IDLE';
  }
  x.display.value = status;
  return status;
}

// Simple function used in asyncCall() to play
function mPlay(ele) {
  var state = 'PLAYING';
  ele.play();
  return state;
}

// Simple function used in asyncCall() to pause
function mIdle(ele) {
  var state = 'IDLE';
  ele.pause();
  return state;
}
```

```css
html {
  font: 400 16px/1.5 Consolas
}

section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 160px);
}

button {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

#playM:before {
  content: '▶';
  font-size: 32px
}

#pauseM::before {
  content: '⏸';
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <video id="A" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm" controls width='160' height='90'></video>
  <video id="B" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm" controls width='160' height='90'></video>
</section>

<form id='ui'>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Asynchronous Playback</legend>

    <button id='playM' type='button'></button>

    <button id='pauseM' type='button'></button>

    <output id='display'></output><br><br>

    <label for='outA'>Source A: </label>
    <output id='outA'></output><br><br>

    <label for='outB'>Source B: </label>
    <output id='outB'></output><br><br>

  </fieldset>
</form>
```

### References

- [**`async`**](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await) `function() {...` [**`await`**](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await)
- [**HTMLFormControlsCollection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection)
- [**Event.target**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)
- `Event.target` [**`.addEventListener(`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) `'event'`, `function`, `false` **`)`**

Comment: Really appreciate your effort. I learn a lot inspired by you. Although your solution is more likely the answer to "how to sync media perfectly in HTML?". I had sort of found what I originally looked for and I will change title of this subject. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You are very welcome, sir. Did you need help on a slightly different question or is it different enough that's it's a new question? If the former, you could add it to this post. If the latter, you're probably better off posting it as a new question.  Either way I'll try to help if I can, happy coding.

Comment: Just saw your edit, and the SO Police ain't gonna like it. Your original post with code was fine, I'll roll it back for you.

Comment: I don't see any edit history so I tried to remember the OP (Original Post). Turns out that by trying to recreate your code I found another way to synchronize media. Just add `D.click()` to the `A` callback function which basically clicks the `B` button when `A` button is clicked. It's probably has a larger offset than my answer, but to my ears there's no echo.

Comment: Well, it seems I have to be more cautious about the CO rules. Thanks bruv for editing for me. I think I'd better editing it myself and use my rough code.

Comment: Since you said, nice guy, I wonder what would add to your code if I want to seek in one file and as a result, set the other file to that time as well?

Comment: As you can see in my rough code, `.currentTime` has been called recursively, thus clutter occurs when playing. I've read that one approach could be to create a timestamp variable, update `.currentTime` of elements when set variable is greater than a minimum delay, however my reputation is so low that I can't comment to ask. Also due to my reputation, I even can't chat to avoid extended discussions...

Comment: Well you were on the right track about `currentTime`. See my updated answer

Comment: Cool. I think I've got the point, and it's time to leave HTML video behind. Essentially my questions are rather academic than practical.

Answer (score 1):

You can use plain JavaScript for this. A good starting point and reference would be [W3C Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp). The `currentTime` property with an `oncuechange` function should get you started in checking changes in the timeline and seeking.

Although, I don't understand your restrictions (if any) so don't know why you wouldn't just use a video file with the audio and video already synced.