# How can I sync audio and video perfectly in JS?

Tags: javascript, audio, video

I'm developing a stream player, I decided to turn off the audio of the video and create individual audios with the languages (audios separately) but the audio never sync. See below:

• Synchronizing the audio based on the video (I'm using the playing event, because timeupdate and progress don't work very well)

```
video.onplaying = function(){ audio.currentTime = Math.round(video.currentTime)}
```

• Getting the difference between the currentTime of the audio and the video (if it is synchronized)

```
video.ontimeupdate = function () {
  document.title = video.currentTime - audio.currentTime; // it oscillates between 0.0535555 and 0.0756795 (Not synchronized)
}
```

I know it seems to want a lot, because I delay it and very little, but there is a way to sync perfectly. (I don't know how the big streams do to get all the languages ​​but this was the personal way I found to solve this)

Comment: The `timeUpdate` event fires @250ms intervals if that helps.

Comment: `timeupdate` doesn't work in this case, because whenever the timeupdate triggers the audio synchronizes with the video a `bleep sound noise` is triggered because the currentTime of the audio has been updated with the currentTime of the video.

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47537707/2813224) out

Comment: Sorry bro, but i don't use async, and seeked or seeking don't work to me bacause any crash, the media loses sync, that's why i'm using playing. But it would be a great alternative if that didn't happen, thanks.

Comment: I was thinking something like, `if the currentTime difference between the two media is greater than 0.07 (when the delay becomes noticeable) synchronize the currentTime of the two media `


video.ontimeupdate = function() {

            if (video.currentTime - audio.currentTime > 0.07) {
                console.log('sync');
                audio.currentTime = video.currentTime - .01
            }
            document.title = video.currentTime - audio.currentTime;
        }

Comment: @zer00ne In the case now, the sync is not giving a lot of beef of noise, and it syncs if there is any ram crash or something, what do you think?

Comment: I think you want something heavy duty, take a look at [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API). With two `<video>` tags it might be to heavy, but with a `<video>` and `<audio>` could be a bit lighter. Also, there's [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) which is open source. I used to use to cut and normalize sound files and sync video to CC.

Comment: @zer00ne Brother, I love you, thats sounds great. Thank you!